# Xcode: Create your own auto-complete

Tags: xcode, typedef

Can I somehow make Xcode to auto-complete my own phrases?
What I want to make is when I typedef a struct to suggest for the new value name the name of the old value with the [*name_of_old_value*]_t?

For Example

```
struct example{
  ...
};
typedef struct example example_t
```

Comment: This behavior should be possible using Xcode snippet feature, see exmaple [here](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/)

Comment: See also https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin

Comment: Thank u guys... gonna check them and tell u which one worked.

Comment: Could this possibly be modified to work for your particular needs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932152/xcode-auto-complete-for-blocks-within-a-block-and-the-blocks-theyre-in